# Filling area with various sized tiles maximum spaced used

Tags: javascript

How to i fille varisus sizes of tiles to specifica area with maximum space used.
Tile order is not important.

I have tiles like those http://vps.infira.ee/temp/before.html
I want that algorith doest that http://vps.infira.ee/temp/after.html (i do that mannualy :) )

I would like to use this algorithm in javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the jQuery Masonry plugin – http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: i have tried this plugin, but this is not what i need, this masonry works almoust, but works only when the blocks is devided by 2, 4 , 6 aso. And the blocks is devided by columns
If to used this plugins with the block wich with's are like 141, and 93
Then it doesnt use maximum space. Blocks are devided by coluns

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment, @Infira, but I am pretty sure jQuery Masonry doesn't set any restriction on the number of elements in the columns. Moreover the number of elements in rows differes based on the free space. Check out Demos section on the plugin's web site.

Comment: The masinry puts the blocks into columns i dont want that, and in my case it doesnt work correctly
see for you self http://vps.infira.ee/temp/beforeMasinory.html